# Upload Image, shuffle it and display

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an issue with my fiddle. I am trying to upload an image from my PC then it is sliced and all the squares are shuffled. I managed to create functions to upload the image and others to slice and shuffle an image from the web but I cannot make them work together. Can you help me out? the code is the one that follows:

```js
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
}


var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rows=6;
var cols=6;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img = document.getElementById("myImg");
function start(){

  var iw=canvas.width=img.width;
  var ih=canvas.height=img.height;
  var pieceWidth=iw/cols;
  var pieceHeight=ih/rows;

  var pieces = [
    {col:0,row:0},
    {col:1,row:0},
    {col:2,row:0},
    {col:3,row:0},
    {col:4,row:0},
    {col:5,row:0},
    {col:0,row:1},
    {col:1,row:1},
    {col:2,row:1},
    {col:3,row:1},
    {col:4,row:1},
    {col:5,row:1},
    {col:0,row:2},
    {col:1,row:2},
    {col:2,row:2},
    {col:3,row:2},
    {col:4,row:2},
    {col:5,row:2},
    {col:0,row:3},
    {col:1,row:3},
    {col:2,row:3},
    {col:3,row:3},
    {col:4,row:3},
    {col:5,row:3},
    {col:0,row:4},
    {col:1,row:4},
    {col:2,row:4},
    {col:3,row:4},
    {col:4,row:4},
    {col:5,row:4},
    {col:0,row:5},
    {col:1,row:5},
    {col:2,row:5},
    {col:3,row:5},
    {col:4,row:5},
    {col:5,row:5},
  ]
    shuffle(pieces);

    var i=0;
    for(var y=0;y<rows;y++){
    for(var x=0;x<cols;x++){
    var p=pieces[i++];
  ctx.drawImage(
    // from the original image
    img,
    // take the next x,y piece
    x*pieceWidth, y*pieceHeight, pieceWidth, pieceHeight,
    // draw it on canvas based on the shuffled pieces[] array
    p.col*pieceWidth, p.row*pieceHeight, pieceWidth, pieceHeight
  );
}}


}

function shuffle(a){
  for(var j, x, i = a.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = a[--i], a[i] = a[j], a[j] = x);
  return a;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:0px solid ;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='file' />
<img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" />
<canvas id="canvas" width=1080 height=1080></canvas>
```

Comment: Javascript and Java are completely different things or how is you question connected to Java?

Comment: As you type in the tag input, it shows a brief explanation of each tag. Please read those and only select those tags that are relevant to your question. For instance, "fiddle" is a tag which refers to a component for the ruby language, which your question does not reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you set the `onload` handler then right after overwrite the `img` variable. In this code the first 2 lines are essentially dead code because of the 3rd line.

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img = document.getElementById("myImg");
```

You should instead just grab the element and add your handler after.

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
img.onload=start;
```